# OpenCV hand recognition?

Tags: c++, opencv, gestures, background-subtraction

After spending on a while on this, I finally managed to detect the hands through thresholding. The only problem is that VERY FEW pixels in the background remain, which will mess up the next step. Any suggestions on how to get rid of the few background pixels? Because I don't want to go through the whole background subtraction thing for just a few pixels. Background Subtraction is not an option for the program, so please don't suggest it

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to share more of the algorithm and maybe some sample images to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without a more detailed description of your hand detection algorithm. If you have a few background pixels that are isolated from the hands you have detected, I would suggest morphological operation like [opening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_%28morphology%29) to eliminate single pixel detections in your binary mask. In openCV, I think you need to [erode](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_image_filtering.html#erode) and then [dilate](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_image_filtering.html#dilate)

Comment: i already tried opening, closing eroding and dilating- they take away most of the pixels, but still keep a few
I need a completely clean background

Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh and for a better description
I am not allowed to share code
but my algorithm is relatively simple
i take two cvScalar values, and just use CvInRangeS() on them
i then Gaussian, open the image twice
Any other suggestions?